# SVO : Fast - Coner Detector - Installation: Plain CMake (No ROS)

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a project of drone and I'm having an issue with my Raspberry Pi 2 B. When I'm trying to install [Fast - Corner Detector](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Installation:-Plain-CMake-(No-ROS)) I get this on screen

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/workspace/fast/build $ make

/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/pi/workspace/fast -B/home/pi/workspace/fast/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/pi/workspace/fast/build/CMakeFiles /home/pi/workspace/fast/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/fast.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/fast.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
cd /home/pi/workspace/fast/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/pi/workspace/fast /home/pi/workspace/fast /home/pi/workspace/fast/build /home/pi/workspace/fast/build /home/pi/workspace/fast/build/CMakeFiles/fast.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/fast.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/fast.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/pi/workspace/fast/build/CMakeFiles 1
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fast.dir/src/fast_10.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -Dfast_EXPORTS -DTEST_DATA_DIR=\"/home/pi/workspace/fast/test/data\" -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/home/pi/workspace/fast/include -I/home/pi/workspace/fast/src -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include    -o CMakeFiles/fast.dir/src/fast_10.cpp.o -c /home/pi/workspace/fast/src/fast_10.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmmx’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse2’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-msse3’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mssse3’
CMakeFiles/fast.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fast.dir/src/fast_10.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fast.dir/src/fast_10.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fast.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fast.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/workspace/fast/build'
Makefile:119: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have Cmake installed (sudo apt-get cmake), Gcc (4.6.3) and OpenCV.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Should perhaps be moved to the Raspberry pi stack exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is ARM, -msse* does it apply. Based on the CMakeFile, they detect ARM and disabled SSE flags. Maybe it is not working for you, perhaps due to a different cmake version

Try changing this

```
IF(DEFINED ENV{ARM_ARCHITECTURE})
```

to

```
IF(DEFINED $ENV{ARM_ARCHITECTURE})
```

This is line 34 in CMakeLists.txt

If the fix does not work, then you could manually enable ARM specified flags by editing CMakeLists.txt

Remove this:

```
IF(DEFINED ENV{ARM_ARCHITECTURE})
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mfpu=neon -march=armv7-a")
ELSE()
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mmmx -msse -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3")
ENDIF()
```

and replace with this

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mfpu=neon -march=armv7-a")
```

Maybe report an issue on github and tell the authors about it.

**EDIT**: you want to do these edits in https://github.com/uzh-rpg/fast/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Also try setting export ARM_ARCHITECTURE=1 before compiling